# Link does not remember the page before

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working in a CSS grid. I have a column where I added a background image. I have made that background image into a hyperlink (`link-x`) with the below javascript.

The problem is not the following. If I do the following:

I go to `https://my-site.com`and click on the hyperlink `link-x`. I click on "back in the browser, which means I should go back to `https://my-site.com`. But when I click back I am getting to my browser startpage.

It seems like the browser does not know the previous page I have been on my website.

Does anybody knows if there is a solution to this?

```js
$('.sbp-item1').click(function(e) {
  window.location.replace("https://my-site.com/link-x");
});
```

```css
.sbp-item1 {
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  grid-column: 1/9;
  height: 520px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-image: url("/Static/Cms/d1bd45c5-f39e-4b8f-8c47-f7fe5497b1a4.jpg");
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="sbp-wrapper">
  <a class="sbp-item1 bg-img" href="https://my-site.com/link-x"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: And this is happening on all browsers? Do you have cache turned off or something in your developer tools by chance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entire point of `replace` is that it **replaces** the current page in the browser history.

Assign the new URL to `location` if you want to navigate normally:

```
window.location = "https://my-site.com/link-x";
```

Comment: Thank for the answer @quentin. I am not quite sure how to set that in my javascript code? Best regards.

Comment: @MK-DK — You replace the line `window.location.replace("https://my-site.com/link-x");` with this

Comment: Sorry, I did not see your answer correctly. Thank you a lot, I marked your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.sbp-item1').click( function(e){
 history.pushState({}, window.location.href); //Maintain history 
    window.location.replace("https://my-site.com/link-x");
});
```

Comment: That's … ludicrous. It makes no sense to duplicate the current URL in the history and then replace one of the two entries with a different one. Just add the different one and don't touch the current one.

Comment: @Quentin. Thanks for the comment. Okay I did not know that. Can you please provide with an example?

Comment: @MK-DK — I posted an answer half an hour ago.